# Mock a boto3 client exception

Tags: python, mocking, boto3, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to mock a call to a function in `boto3.client("cognito-idp")`.
I've been able to successfully mock for the normal flow of code but exceptions are proving trickier.  I've got something like:

```py
@patch("boto3.client")
def test_failure_cannot_create_duplicate_user_in_cognito(self, mock_client):
  client = boto3.client("cognito-idp")
  boto3_mock = MagicMock()
  boto3_mock.admin_create_user.side_effect = client.exceptions.UsernameExistsException()
  mock_client.return_value = boto3_mock
  response = handler(event, None)
  body = json.loads(response["body"])
  self.assertEqual(HTTPStatus.CONFLICT, response["statusCode"])
```

and then in the handler:

```
client = boto3.client("cognito-idp")
try:
    create_user_response = client.admin_create_user(
      UserPoolId=user_pool,
      Username=user_name,
      UserAttributes=[
        {
           "Name": user_attribute,
           "Value": user_name
        },
        {
            "Name": verify,
            "Value": "True"
        },
      ],
      TemporaryPassword=temp_pass,
            DesiredDeliveryMediums=[delivery],
    )
    cognito_user_name = create_user_response["User"]["Username"]
except client.exceptions.UsernameExistsException:
   return conflict(Errors.DUPLICATE_USER)
```

The `except` isn't handling the exception.

Comment: Perhaps use [moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto) could help you

Answer (score 1):

[`moto`](https://pypi.org/project/moto/) aside, it is with some effort possible to raise a specific boto3 exception from a mocked boto3 function using [this approach by mixja](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2485#issuecomment-752454137).

Before continuing, note that [stubber](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/stubber.html) isn't a good option because it typically requires `~/.aws/` configuration file(s) to exist, and they generally don't exist in a CI (continuous integration) environment.

Here is an example over `boto3.client('glue')` using the aforementioned approach. It can be adapted for other AWS services and exceptions.

Function:

```py
def ensure_crawler(**kwargs: Any) -> None:
    client = boto3.client("glue")
    try:
        response = client.create_crawler(**kwargs)
    except client.exceptions.AlreadyExistsException:
        response = client.update_crawler(**kwargs)
    assert response["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"] == 200
```

Tests:

```py
import botocore.errorfactory
import botocore.session

_GLUE_MODEL = botocore.session.get_session().get_service_model("glue")
_GLUE_FACTORY = botocore.errorfactory.ClientExceptionsFactory()
_GLUE_EXCEPTIONS = _GLUE_FACTORY.create_client_exceptions(_GLUE_MODEL)


class TestEnsureCrawler(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.crawler = "abc-crawler"
        self.mock_boto3_client = patch("boto3.client").start()

    def test_create_crawler(self):
        self.mock_boto3_client.return_value.create_crawler.return_value = {"ResponseMetadata": {"HTTPStatusCode": 200}}
        kwargs = dict(Name=self.crawler, Targets={"S3Targets": [{"Path": "s3://foo/bar"}]})
        ensure_crawler(**kwargs)

        self.mock_boto3_client.return_value.create_crawler.assert_called_once()
        call_args = self.mock_boto3_client.return_value.create_crawler.call_args
        self.assertEqual(call_args.args, ())
        self.assertLessEqual(kwargs.items(), call_args.kwargs.items())

    def test_update_crawler(self):
        self.mock_boto3_client.return_value.exceptions.AlreadyExistsException = _GLUE_EXCEPTIONS.AlreadyExistsException
        self.mock_boto3_client.return_value.create_crawler.side_effect = _GLUE_EXCEPTIONS.AlreadyExistsException({}, "")
        self.mock_boto3_client.return_value.update_crawler.return_value = {"ResponseMetadata": {"HTTPStatusCode": 200}}
        kwargs = dict(Name=self.crawler, Targets={"S3Targets": [{"Path": "s3://foo/bar"}]})
        ensure_crawler(**kwargs)

        self.mock_boto3_client.return_value.update_crawler.assert_called_once()
        call_args = self.mock_boto3_client.return_value.update_crawler.call_args
        self.assertEqual(call_args.args, ())
        self.assertLessEqual(kwargs.items(), call_args.kwargs.items())
```